# Create many pages with dynamic content based on 1 template

Tags: pages

I have created one page that looks exactly the way I want.

I would like that page to be the template for hundreds of pages. The content on those new pages should be grabbed from a database. When I say content I mean various elements, from the youtube video to the title and meta description. From the introtext to the text in an accordion at the bottom. The database controls which url exists or not.

When I change the template, for example add a button. It has to change on all the pages.

Is this possible with wordpress? I don't even know where to begin searching.

I was/am considering abandoning wordpress and just have a static html/css/js template and pull the data straight from a database...

Comment: Yes it is possible with WordPress

Comment: Can you also point me in the right direction moshin?

Comment: WordPress custom post type or pages custom templates will fully support it. You just need to build one template and then for all the pages you create can pull data from database and use the template markup and design. So updating in future anything in the template will instantly be available in all pages or custom post type posts due to common template. Please read about custom page template WordPress or CPT.

Answer (score 0):

In case the Multisite functionality of WordPress is an option for you, then that would be the perfect use case for the template functionality of WordPress. You install your template on the multisite, "activate it for all sites" to be used and voilà, it should change on all "networksites".

See the [official documentation](https://wordpress.org/support/article/create-a-network/) as a first start.
Besides that, there are hundrets of tutorials on the web and here on WPSE on this topic.

In case your sites are scattered all over the web and on different servers, then using .GIT repositories for this would be the right approach in my opinion.